# How to aggregate using ddply when not all elements of a variable exist on R

Tags: r, merge, plyr

I am having trouble using combinations of ddply and merge to aggregate some variables. The data frame that I am using is really large, so I am putting an example below:

```
data_sample <- cbind.data.frame(c(123,123,123,321,321,134,145,000),
                               c('j', 'f','j','f','f','o','j','f'),
                               c(seq(110,180, by = 10)))

colnames(data_sample) <- c('Person','Expense_Type','Expense_Value')
```

I want to calculate, for each person, the percentage of the value of expense of type j on the person's total expense.

```
data_sample2 <- ddply(data_sample, c('Person'), transform, total = sum(Value))
data_sample2 <- ddply(data_sample2, c('Person','Type'), transform, empresa = sum(Value))
```

This it what I've done to list total expenses by type, but the problem is that not all individuals have expenses of type j, so their percentage should be 0 and I don't know how to leave only one line per person with the percentage of total expenses of type j.

I might have not made myself clear.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `by` function:

```
by(data_sample, data_sample$Person, FUN = function(dat){
    sum(dat[dat$Expense_Type == 'j',]$Expense_Value) / sum(dat$Expense_Value)
})
```

We could also make use of the **`dplyr`** package:

```
library(dplyr)
data_sample %>%
    group_by(Person) %>%
    summarise(Percent_J = sum(ifelse(Expense_Type == 'j', Expense_Value, 0)) / sum(Expense_Value))

# A tibble: 5 × 2
  Person Percent_J
   <dbl>     <dbl>
1      0 0.0000000
2    123 0.6666667
3    134 0.0000000
4    145 1.0000000
5    321 0.0000000
```

Comment: Supposing that there were other columns on the original dataset whose data vary only according to the Person. How could I leave those values after making the aggregation?

Comment: So for each person it's the same value (e.g. Person A only has x for all rows, Person B only has y for all rows...)? A `merge` to a distinct table would probably work. Otherwise you could add the variables to the `group_by` in `dplyr`.

Comment: Sorry, my votes are not displayed since I do not have enough reputation.